# Xcode6 how to set class prefix when create a new project?

Tags: xcode

Unlike Xcode5, when create new project, there is not a input field for class prefix.

Did Apple abandon it?

Comment: would you mind to accept my answer?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Apple abandoned it.

> After much deliberation, engineering has removed this feature.
>
> This was removed intentionally. We are no longer encouraging the use of prefixes for app code, and for frameworks, you can create a prefix in the Project Inspector after creating the project.

Additional information can be found in [this article](http://scottberrevoets.com/2014/07/25/objective-c-prefixes-a-thing-of-the-past/).